# How to publish a notification to 80K devices without so much delay?

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

It takes about 1.5-2 minutes to send a notification to 80K devices using Google Cloud Messaging. Is this duration normal or is there any workaround to send it in 5 or 10 seconds ?

Sending 80 requests to GCM server takes only 1 second, but the last package's response takes about 1.5 minute.

Thanks

Comment: I doubt you are going to be able to speed up GCM, If you want it quicker you'll prolly have to shop around for a different push service. That being said I doubt you're going to find one that is going to guaruntee you 80k messages in 5-10 seconds, and if you do it is probably not going to be cheap. In the grand scheme of things is 1.5 to 2 minutes really so long to wait for 80 thousand messages? That still averages out to about 667 message per second...pretty good for a free service if you ask me.

Comment: Yes, it is pretty good for a free service but we are able to do it on ios push notification.

Answer (score 0):

Look at a service like Xtify.com and use their BulkPush API. Not positive but I believe they support up to 100k pushes every 2 seconds. Then your delivery time is simply dependent on the GCM servers.

Comment: I did 80K pushes in 1 second but the problem is the delivery time.